# Preferences only show NAT in VirtualBox on Linux

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am trying to set up a Host-only network on linux. But virtual box's preference window only show the NAT screen.

[image]

What is the correct way to set up a host-only network?

On the individual VM's settings screen, if I try to create a host-only network the dropdown will be empty and it won't allow to save.

Comment: In the Virtual Box documentation following, read section 6.7 for the Host Only setup. There are a few steps and it is more complicated than VMware Workstation (I use this). https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2019, on version of VirtualBox 6.0, Oracle has moved the host-only network tab. Now “Preferences > Network” is only for the NAT settings, there is no other tab there.

For other non-NAT networks, use “File > Host Network Manager.”

Answer (score 1):

## The networking settings that would allow “Host Only” exist within the settings of an individual virtual machine and not the main app preferences themselves.

I forgot the reason why this is the case, but “Host Only” only shows up in network settings on a per-virtual machine basis. Confirmed using the latest VirtualBox (6.0.14) macOS Catalina (10.15.1).

Here is my “Network” config area from the main “VirtualBox -> Preferences…” menu:

[image: Screenshot of the VirtualBox “Network” settings under “Preferences” in macOS.]

Now look at the “Network” values “Settings…” under settings when a test machine is setup:

[image: Screenshot of the “Settings” for an individual virtual machine in macOS.]

Note that “Attached to:” menu list. Here are the values present:

[image: Values under “Attached to:” in the “Settings” for an individual virtual machine in macOS.]

Comment: If you select Host-only there, it will enable the Name dropdown, but the only option will be "not selected" and it won't allow you to save.

Comment: Did you also review Chapter 8 in the document reference above?

Comment: @gcb Try creating a second adapter. I believe if you keep the main adapter “NAT Network” and the second one “Host-only Adapter” you should be good to go.

Comment: @John No I didn’t. I simply use VirtuaBox and have experience creating Vagrant scripts using VirtualBox as well. If you have an answer, please post it. But when you state, “Did you also review Chapter 8 in the document reference above?” I did not. Clicking on that link takes me to chapter 6 and subhead 8 — assuming that is what you mean — is “UDP Tunnel Networking” which seems off-topic and definitely overkill. Setting up a host-only network on VirtualBox is not hard… Once you understand how it works.

Comment: No luck. I'm probably missing something. Just realized bridged and host-only are "extra" install options on windows. And on ubuntu there is net/Host-only on the main preference, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/198452/no-host-only-adapter-selected  I am likely missing the host-only network and/or support for it on the Host.

Comment: lol. That askubuntu question has the solution buried in a comment. will add to a proper answer! thanks everyone!